# Ajax ScriptManager EnableHistory property not found exception

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am getting following exceptions while compiling asp.net web site which uses ajax 1.1. Now the funny thing is that it gets compile sometimes and sometimes not!

1)      Error      330         Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'OnNavigate'.

2)      Error      331         Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'EnableHistory'.

Some guys suggest to install .net fm 3.5 sp1, this i have alreday installed but does not help.

Please help me out on this.

Regards,

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the web site from solution and added again, then complied, it worked.